# Label Printer for Javascript based web application

Tags: zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I'm not sure whether there is a solution to my requirement. But I'm searching for a solution to print labels from browser with any JavaScript based web application, where I should be able to print using the printer IP Address, but not with any driver installation to the pc.

In simple terms, the clients using my web application should be able to connect and print just by adding the IP Address to web app without any driver installation.

Are there any such solutions ?

Comment: you can work with generic text printer drivers. they already come with the OS.